# Problem on Loading Map Into div

Tags: javascript, maps

I'm using Google Maps API v3. When I'm loading map into a div, it doesnt load as I expected..
The map area takes the whole div, but the map only loads into top left of the div(only a part).. All the controls including zooming, are loading normally, How can I fix this
?

Comment: It would help if you show us your source code, preferably together with an example page.

Comment: Did you style the map dive? This would cause what you describe:
<div id="map" style="width: 50%; height: 50%;"></div>

Answer (score 0):

You should set the size of the map:

http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/v2/reference.html#GSize